Cellcolor overlaps Table border in tabularx
In continuation of my previous question Table with multiple different colored cells, I want to resolve a somewhat minor issue.
What I wanted to do is that the \cellcolor must not overlap the table boundary. For example, there must not be an overlap between row1.row1 and row2.row2.
I have tried the following:
answer1,
answer2
Problem: They seem not to be consistent with tabularx.
Note: I want to stick to tabularx. Moreover, MWE represents only part of a long table spanning 3 pages.
MWE:`
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}
{\linewidth}{@{}|l|X|X|X|X|X|@{}}
\caption{long table spanning across 3 pages.}
\label{tab:tab} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}         & \textbf{Col3} & \textbf{Col4} & \textbf{Col5}& \textbf{Col6} \\  
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}         & \textbf{Col3} & \textbf{Col4} & \textbf{Col5}& \textbf{Col6} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
  &    & D\&D:B2-3 & N/A  &N/A  & long text \\ \cline{2-6} 
 \hline
 some text  & \multirow{3}{*}{some text} & \textbf{AAA}:DD & N/A    & \multirow{3}{*} {\cellcolor{orange}}{IR.IR, IR.RI}& long text                     \\ \cline{3-6} 
 &    &  & N/A  & \multirow{3}{*} {\cellcolor{blue!30}}{AA.AA}&\\
 &    &  &   & \multirow{3}{*} {\cellcolor{gray!20}}{MG.DG}&\\ 
 &    &  &   & \multirow{3}{*} {\cellcolor{red!20}}{BB.BB} & more text \\ \cline{2-6}
\end{tabularx}
% \end{landscape}

\end{document}

`

nicematrix provides an environment {NiceTabularX} with the same syntax as {tabularx} (of the package tabularx). In that environment, the rules won't seem to disappear under the colored panels.

If you are using colortbl color I really wouldn't use vertical rules. (actually I wouldn't use vertical rules and color whichever package you use) but if you do want that I would take @F.Pantigny's advice and use nicematrix. (You may note the authors of tabularx/colortbl and nicematrix :-)


From your MWE is not clear why you need multi row cells (sine in your code are not rows, which they spanned). Consequently in MWE below I a redesign you table accordingly (that multi row cells have sense)
A possible solution is use of longtblr of tabularray package and define macro to coloring cells:

\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell{bg=#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {long table spanning across 3 pages.},
  label = {tab:tab}     
                ]{colspec = {l *{5}{X[l]}},
                  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                  rowhead = {1},
                  vlines
                  }
    \toprule
Col 1   &   Col 2   &   Col 3   &   Col 4   &   Col 5   &   Col 6       \\
    \midrule
        &           & D\&D: B2-3
                                &   N/A     &   N/A     & long text     \\
        \cline{2-6}
some text  
        &   some text 
                    & \textbf{AAA}: DD       
                                & N/A    
                                            &   \SetCell[r=3]{} \SCC{orange}  IR.IR, IR.RI
                                                        & long text     \\
        &           &           &           &           &               \\ 
        &           &           &           &           &               \\
        \cline{3-6}
        &           &           & N/A       &   \SetCell[r=3]{} \SCC{blue!30} AA.AA
                                                        &               \\
        &           &           &           &           &               \\
        &           &           &           &           &               \\
        \cline{3-6}
        &           &           &           &   \SetCell[r=3]{} \SCC{gray!20}   MG.DG
                                                        &               \\
        &           &           &           &           &               \\
        &           &           &           &           &               \\
        \cline{3-6}
        &           &           &           &   \SetCell[r=3]{} \SCC{red!20}    BB.BB
                                                        &   more text   \\ 
        &           &           &           &           &               \\
        &           &           &           &           &               \\
    \cline{2-6}
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
% \end{landscape}

\end{document}



I have followed @F. Pantigny to resolve the issue. Thank you.

as I stated I shared only a part of the table plus I want to stick to tabularx.

All is up to you. If you not liked simple, well working solution, than wait on some others (nicematrix is not tabularx, BTW).

Thank you. I do agree with your suggestion and solution (accepted it). \hhline{~|-|-|-|} solved issue for me. It took me some time. I was looking for something with minimum changes as my document has many tables.

@user3582228, I dont see any reason to use hhline package. For more complete solution I need to know more table content (what is in the first column and second column, are multi row cells are really needed, etc). Content of cells not need to be real one, some dummy content is sufficient.
